# iptables ignoring the device

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have 3 eth-interfaces on my system.

eth0, wlan0 and lo

Why is iptalbes allowing this command without an error???
foobar9 is not one of my devices.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i foobar9 -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

Output of iptables -L -n is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  1.2.3.4              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1234
```

iptables v1.6.2 on a Debian 10

Comment: Debian Buster = Testing = 10

Comment: It can be your device anytime.

Comment: Well ok, that is true.

Comment: I could almost ask *why should there be an error?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this on my machine and it turns out iptables doesn't care about the interface names.

I know for a fact that the `ip route` command does care that the interface exists but iptables apparently does not.

A helpful command for you would be `iptables -vL`, as it shows the interface names for the rules in your chains.

My test was done on a Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.9.7, iptables v1.6.0.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i bumbum -j ACCEPT
iptables -vL
```

Resulting output on my machine is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1842 packets, 2569K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  bumbum any     anywhere             anywhere
```